# Memory used increases with tkinter notebook and matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, memory, tkinter

I've got a small program that creates a GUI using tkinter. It contains a button that loads a .csv file, creates a notebook with as many tabs as columns in the csv file. Then, on every active tab (at least this is my intention) I have a plot created from a Figure.

The program works as expected , the only problem is that when switching Tabs, the memory used increases with each Tab click. 
Memory usage was monitored using the Windows Task Manager. 
After loading a csv file, I didn't see the used memory dropping when I chose not loading a new file.
If I don't call the plotting function, when creating only the Tabs, there is no memory issue.
I already tried to manually invoke the garbage collector with gc.collect(), but that didn't help. This is the code I have:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
##import gc

class Graphs(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self._destroyWindow)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def _destroyWindow(self):
        self.quit()    # stops mainloop
        self.destroy()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # initialize lists
        self.tabs_list = []
        self.hdrs = []
        self.figs_list = []
        self.ax_list = []
        self.canvas_list = []
        self.toolbars_list = []

        # initialize Data Frame
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()

        self.nb = None
        self.canvas = None
        self.toolbar = None

        # create LOAD button
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text = 'Load file', command=self.load_csv)
        self.btn.pack()

    def load_csv(self):
        ''' 
            Reset Data Frame;
            Destroy notebook if exists;
            Load CSV file.
        '''

        # reset Data Frame
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()

        # destroy notebook if exists
        if self.nb:
            self.nb.pack_forget()
            self.nb.destroy()

        self.nb = None

##        gc.collect()

        # Select CSV file
        self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

        if not self.file_path:
            msg.showinfo('Select CSV file', "No file chosen.")
            return
        try:
            # read csv file (exemple.csv)
            self.df = pd.read_csv(self.file_path, header=0)
        except:
            msg.showinfo('Select CSV file', 'Not a csv file / corrupt file.')
            return

        print(self.df.head())
        print(self.df.shape)
        # get dimensions
        self.m, self.n = self.df.shape

        # build the abscissa x from first column
        self.x = self.df.iloc[:,0]

        # create the notebook
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self)

        # allow Tab navigation
        self.nb.enable_traversal()

        # add Tabs
        for k in range(1, self.n):
            hdr = self.df.columns[k]
            self.hdrs.append(hdr)

            tab = tk.Frame(self.nb, name=hdr.lower())
            self.nb.add(tab, text=hdr)

            self.tabs_list.append(tab)

        self.nb.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

        # virtual event after a new tab is selected
        self.nb.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.plotTH)


    def plotTH(self, event):

        '''
            Plot each Column from Data Frame on its own Tab/Figure
        '''

        # get path of the selected Tab
        tab_path = event.widget.nametowidget(event.widget.select())

        # add selected Tab to the list of Tabs
        self.tabs_list.append(tab_path)

        # get the Tab index;
        # When there are no tabs, .select() returns an empty string,
        # but .index('current') throws an exception;
        # nb.select() returns the Tab NAME (string) of the current selection
        if self.nb.select():
            i = self.nb.index('current')
            # get the Tab text
            tab_text = self.nb.tab(i)['text']
        else:
            return

        # remove previous figures ... not sure...
        # the used memory as seen in Task Manager still increases
        if self.canvas_list:
            for cnv in self.canvas_list:

                cnv.figure.get_axes().clear()

                cnv.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()
                cnv.get_tk_widget().destroy()

                cnv._tkcanvas.pack_forget()
                cnv._tkcanvas.destroy()

                cnv = None

        if self.figs_list:

            for fig in self.figs_list:
                fig.delaxes(fig.gca())
                plt.cla()
                fig.clf()
                fig.clear()
                plt.close(fig)
            self.figs_list = []

        # remove toolbar           
        for widget in tab_path.winfo_children():
            widget.pack_forget()
            widget.destroy()

        self.nb.update()    #!!!!!!!!!!!!

########        gc.collect()

        # prepare plotting
        fig = Figure(figsize=(7, 5), dpi=100)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        ax.plot(self.x, self.df.iloc[:,i+1], 'b-', linewidth=1, label=tab_text)
        ax.set_xlabel('index')
        ax.set_title(self.hdrs[i], fontsize = 8)
        ax.legend(loc='best')
        ax.grid()

        # add to list of figures
        self.figs_list.append(fig)
        # add to list of axes
        self.ax_list.append(ax)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=tab_path)

        # add to list of canvases
        self.canvas_list.append(canvas)
##        self.canvas.draw()
        canvas.draw_idle()

        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, tab_path)

        # add to list of toolbars
        self.toolbars_list.append(toolbar)
        toolbar.update()

        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def clearPlot(self):
        """ not used"""
        pass


app = Graphs()
app.title('CSV Plots')
app.geometry('800x600+400+150')
app.resizable(True, True)

app.mainloop();
```

I created a working csv file using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50,4), columns=['ALPHA', 'BETA', 'GAMMA', 'DELTA'])

df.index.names = ['Rec']

df.index = df.index + 1

df.to_csv('example.csv', index=True)

print(df)
```

I'm sorry for the long post. I really don't know were to go from here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi your script work except for the matter that the notebook isn't create. Can you control this?

Comment: tab = tk.Frame(self.nb, name=hdr.lower()), where is this widget packed?

Comment: @1966bc: Hi, thank you for your feedback. If I'm not missing something, following some documentation about tkinter notebook, I create a tabControl (aka notebook) with: self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self); the packing is done by: self.nb.pack(fill='both', expand=1).

Answer (score 0):

None of the following lists are ever purged; they hold references to large objects that cannot be garbage collected.

```
self.tabs_list = []
self.hdrs = []
self.figs_list = []
self.ax_list = []
self.canvas_list = []
self.toolbars_list = []
```

You probably should create an object that holds the data for each tab, and `destroy/purge/reassign to None` that when changing tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code; I realized I was creating a new figure (with all the Artists) and a new canvas (FigureCanvasTkAgg) with every TabChanged event. Instead, I create a figure and its canvas at the moment of Tab addition to the notebook; I do the plot only when the TabChanged occurs and I take care to close all the plots and to destroy the previous notebook when performing a new CSV file load. Destroying the notebook removes the canvases too. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.style as mplstyle
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os, sys, time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog


mplstyle.use('fast')

class Graphs(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self._destroyWindow)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def _destroyWindow(self):
        self.quit()    # stops mainloop
        self.destroy()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # initialize Data Frame
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()

        self.nb = None
        self.fig = None
        self.canvas = None
        self.toolbar = None

        # create LOAD button
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text = 'Load file', command=self.load_csv)
        self.btn.pack()

    def load_csv(self):
        ''' Close the plots;
            Reset Data Frame;
            Destroy notebook if exists;
            Load CSV file.
        '''

        # Setting interactive mode off
        if plt.isinteractive():
            plt.ioff()

        plt.close("all")

        # reset Data Frame
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()

        # initialize list
        self.hdrs = []

        try:
            # destroy notebook if exists
            self.nb.pack_forget()
            self.nb.destroy()
        except:
            pass

        self.nb = None

        # Select CSV file
        self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

        if not self.file_path:
            msg.showinfo('Select CSV file', "No file chosen.")
            return
        try:
            # read csv file (exemple.csv)
            self.df = pd.read_csv(self.file_path, header=0)
        except:
            msg.showinfo('Select CSV file', 'Not a csv file / corrupt file.')
            return

        # get dimensions
        self.m, self.n = self.df.shape

        # build the abscissa x from first column
        self.x = self.df.iloc[:,0]

        # create the notebook
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self)

        # allow Tab navigation
        self.nb.enable_traversal()

        # add Tabs
        for k in range(1, self.n):
            hdr = self.df.columns[k]
            self.hdrs.append(hdr)

            tab = tk.Frame(self.nb, name=hdr.lower())
            self.nb.add(tab, text=hdr)

            self.fig = plt.figure(num=hdr.lower(), clear=True, figsize=(7, 5), dpi=100)
            # self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot()
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=tab)
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, tab)
            toolbar.update()
            self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.nb.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

        # virtual event after a new tab is selected
        self.nb.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.plotTH)

    def plotTH(self, event):
        '''
            Plot each Column from Data Frame on its own Tab/Figure
        '''

        # Setting interactive mode on is essential: plt.ion()
        if not plt.isinteractive():
            plt.ion()

        # tab index
        i = self.nb.index('current')

        # tab text
        tab_text = self.nb.select().split('.')[-1]

        # set current figure
        cf = plt.figure(tab_text)
        plt.clf()        

        # plotting
        ax = plt.subplot(111)  

        ax.plot(self.x, self.df.iloc[:,i+1], 'b-', linewidth=1, label=tab_text)
        ax.set_xlabel('index')
        ax.set_title(self.hdrs[i], fontsize = 8)
        ax.legend(loc='best')
        ax.grid()

        cf.canvas.draw()

app = Graphs()
app.title('CSV Plots')
app.geometry('800x600+400+150')
app.resizable(True, True)

app.mainloop()
```